# If there any possible solution (analytical/numerical) of a this nonlinear third order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

The equation I'm trying to solve is the following
$$m_3\ddot{y}^3 + m_1\ddot{y} + k_1 y + k_3y^3 = f_1(t) $$

All the parameters are real $m_1,m_3,k_1,k_3\in \mathbb{R}$ and constant.
$f_1(t)\in \mathbb{R}$ is a function of $t$ as is $y(t)$.
Obviously if $m_3=0$ then the solution can be found because the equation takes the form

$$\ddot{y} =  a y + by^3 + c,$$

where $a=-\dfrac{k_1}{m_1}$, $b = -\dfrac{k_3}{m_1}$, $c = \dfrac{f_1}{m_1}$,
which is the classical form of a nonlinear ODE as
$$ \ddot{y} = F(y,t).$$

**EDIT:**

Please find below my implementation in MATLAB of DAE with NO success so far.

First I define the DAE function as

```
function out = funTest(t,y,yp)

% coefficients
m1 = 9.8845614144e-10;
m3 = 2.00030511601069e-12;

f1 = 1.66666666666667e-05;

k1 = 0.214188819381172;
k3 = 8.6610733212416;

omega = 2*pi*(-82.454*t + 10030);

out = [yp(1) - y(2)
    yp(2) - y(3)
    m3*y(3)^3 + m1*y(3) + k1*y(1) + k3*y(1)^3 - f1*sin(omega*t)];
```

Below the main file

```
tspan = [60 120];
M = [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 0]; % constant mass matrix
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-4,'Jacobian',{[],M});

y0 = [0; 0; 0];
yp0 = [0; 0; 0];
[y0,yp0] = decic(@funTest,0,y0,[1 1 0],yp0,[],options);

[t,y] = ode15i(@funTest,tspan,y0,yp0,options);


plot(t,y(:,1));
ylabel('y');
```

I tried changing both options as

```
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-4,'AbsTol',[1e-10 1e-6 1e-6], ...
   'Jacobian',{[],M});
```

but nothing happens

Comment: You can treat this as a DAE of index 1, $\dot y=v$, $\dot v=q$, $m_3q^3+m_1q+k_1y+k_3y_3=f_1(t)$ and apply any available DAE solver.

Comment: @LutzL numerical implementation of this (like ode45 in MATLAB) requires to have first order derivatives on the left side of = on the contrary this is valid only for the first 2 equations the third does not have any "dot" derivative. Do you have any specific solver in mind?

Comment: That's why I said **DAE** solver. In matlab you have ode23s for semi-explicit and ode15i for implicit DAE.

Comment: @LutzL I’m not an expert of DAE but it does not seem to work. Since solution coincides with initial conditions defined by decic MATLAB command without any time variation

Comment: You can of course also take the derivative of the equation to get an explicit expression for $\dddot y$. Then you need to enlarge the initial state from $(t_0;y_0,\dot y_0)$ to $(t_0;y_0,\dot y_0,\ddot y_0)$ by once solving the cubic and selecting one of the real roots.

Comment: If the constants $m_k$ are positive, then the leading expression $m_3\ddot y^3+m_1\ddot y$ is strictly monotonic and thus invertible as a real function. This means that in computing $\ddot y=F(t,y)$ you need to solve the cubic, numerically or using the Cardano formulas.

Comment: @LutzL First how can you write $\ddot{y}=F(t,y)$ if a cubic expression of $\ddot{y}^3$ is present. Second DAE solution is MATLAB seems very unstable I tried many times but my equation never got into a reasonable solution after a few milli-seconds stops or even in some cases do not run at all. I include my implementation as a EDIT

Comment: Let $v=\phi(u)$ be the inverse function to $m_3v^3+m_1v=u$, which is well-defined for $m_1,m_2>0$. Then $F(t,y)=\phi(f(t)-k_1y-k_3y^3)$. // I do not know how stable the DAE solvers of Matlab are, there was [some topic recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3364784/115115) that even the documentation example does not work nicely if continued in time.

Comment: As you suspected, you get murdered by the absolute tolerance. Starting at zero, $y$ is completely driven by the forcing term and will thus remain in the scale $10^{-5}$. The absolute tolerance needs to be based on this, to get 6 decimals you need to set AbsTol for $y$ to $10^{-11}$ or smaller.

Comment: Then the cubic terms are relatively irrelevant, so the solution is approximated by the linear DE $m_1\ddot y+k_1y=f(t)$. The left side has a eigen frequency $\sqrt{k_1/m_1}$ on the scale of $10^5$ which will require step sizes in the region of $10^{-6}$ or smaller to get usable results. Another consequence is that $y$ may pass from $-10^{-5}$ to $10^{-5}$ in time $10^{-5}$, so values for $\dot y$ may reach a scale of $10$. Thus the AbsTol for $\dot y$ needs to be based on this, so it remains at $10^{-6}$.

Comment: The equation itself takes, in the described situation, values in the range $10^{-5}$, so to force some accuracy in its solution you need to set its AbsTol to $10^{-10}$ or smaller.

Comment: @LutzL I'm trying to applying Cardano, meanwhile replying to your comment are you sure that both nonlinear terms are negligible? Not yet sure about $m_3$ but $k_3$ seems highly relevant due to the fact that $k_3/k_1>>0$ leading to strong nonlinear stiffness non linearities

Comment: @LutzL even setting absolute tolerance to $10^{-10}$ the solver does not start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's discuss the scales of the example, where $m_1,m_3,k_1,k_3,f_1$ have scales $10^{-9}, 10^{-12}, 1, 1, 10^{-5}$ respectively. The "easy" adjustments are changing the time scale and the scale of $y$. Set $y(t)=10^{-m}u(10^{n}t)$, then $\ddot y=10^{2n-m}\ddot u(10^{n}t)$ and the transformed equation is
$$
10^{6n-3m}m_3\ddot u(s)^3+10^{2n-m}m_1\ddot u(s)+10^{-3m}k_3u(s)^3+10^{-m}k_1u(s)=f(t)
$$
Now to balance the size of the coefficients, multiply with $10^{m}$ to get
$$
10^{6n-2m}m_3\ddot u(s)^3+10^{2n}m_1\ddot u(s)+10^{-2m}k_3u(s)^3+k_1u(s)=10^{m}f_1\sin(\theta(t)),
$$
and then identify as the active constraints $m\sim 5$ for the right side and  $6n\lesssim 12+2m$ and $2n\lesssim 9$ for the second derivatives. One variant is $m=6$, $n=4$. Then the transformed constants $m_1,m_3,k_1,k_3,f_1$ have the sizes $10^{-1}, 1, 1, 10^{-12}, 10$. The dominant terms now have sizes that are compatible with the internal heuristics and default tolerances of the solvers. One can now translate this rescaling back into sensible absolute tolerances for the problem in the original coefficients. For a goal of 4 valid digits, $y$ would have AbsTol $10^{-m-4}=10^{-10}$, $\dot y$ of $10^{n-m-4}=10^{-6}$ and the equation of $10^{-5-4}=10^{-9}$.

#### Numerical method as ODE solving the cubic in each step

Use the balanced scaling computed above. To solve the cubic $m_3a^3+m_1a=c$ a first approximation is in general $a=(c/m_3)^{1/3}$. For very small $c$ it is $a=c/m_1$. Both behaviors are combined in the formula
$$
a = \frac{c}{(m_1^3+m_3c^2)^{1/3}},~~\text{ or }~~a = \frac{c}{\max(m_1,(m_3c^2)^{1/3})},
$$
which additionally is unproblematic for negative $c$. This gives a very good initial value for the numerical solver `fsolve`.

```
from numpy import sin,pi
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# coefficients
m1 = 9.8845614144e-10*1e8;       # *10^(2n), m=6, n=4
m3 = 2.00030511601069e-12*1e12;  # *10^(6n-2m)

f1 = 1.66666666666667e-05*1e6;   # *10^m

k1 = 0.214188819381172;          # unchanged
k3 = 8.6610733212416*1e-12;      # *10^(-2m)

s0 = 60*1e4; sf = 120*1e4;

# angle function of the forcing
def theta(s): 
    t = 1e-4*s; # s = 10^n*t
    omega = 2*pi*(-82.454*t + 10030); 
    return omega*t;

# system function
def ODEsys(s,u):
    c = f1*sin(theta(s)) - k1*u[0]-k3*u[0]**3;
    du = u[1];
    ddu = fsolve(lambda z: m1*z+m3*z**3-c, c/(m1**3+m3*c**2)**(1./3))
    return [du, ddu]

# compute a small initial segment of the solution
sol = solve_ivp(ODEsys, [s0,s0+1000], [0,0], method='Radau', max_step=1)
# plot in the original scale, t = 10^(-n)*s, y(t)=10^(-m)*u(s)
plt.plot(sol.t*1e-4, sol.y[0]*1e-6);
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

which gives the plot

[image]

For the slightly larger segment to $t=61$ this method gives the plot

[image]

plots for larger time scales like to $t=120$ do not appear sensible.

Comment: @LuzL many thanks for the working python code. However, I need a MATLAB code for several reasons and can you give me some reference on how to convert "fsolve" and "solve_ivp" in MATLAB environment? I just need theoretical references so far did not get any.

Comment: `fsolve` works the same in matlab, and `solve_ivp` can be replaced by `ode45` or `ode113` or any other method of that family. It might be worth some experiments if it is worth to apply a Newton loop directly to $f(z)=m_3z^2+m_1-c/z$ (with this function, Newton is in fact Halley and thus of third order).

Comment: I was able to implement the same in MATLAB successfully. But I'm concerned with your comment "do not appear sensible" thus, you mean that no "resonance" effect can be measured? For linear and non-linear stiff ODE resonance can be carried out but considering $m_3 \neq 0$ seems not possible. How do you explain this?

Comment: No, that referred to "plots". You get estimated 125 large oscillations per time unit, thus 7500 over 60 time units. To see something in the plot you would need at least 4 pixels width per oscillation, thus a plot 30000 pixels wide. This is not impossible, but, as I said, not really sensible for display here.

Comment: You might want to integrate from $t=0$ to $60$ blind and then examine the stabilized solution from $t=60$ to $120$, this might be the intention behind this setup. It appears that there could be a more or less stable limit cycle with 70 cycles per time unit and amplitude about $0.005$, which can not be seen in the "chaotic" plots of the initial phase. For speed it might be sensible to translate this to a compiled language using the ODEPACK Fortran solvers or the julia-lang solver library. Experiments with the full interval take some time in python and probably matlab too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to avoid the potential complex solutions for the cubic. Using a symbolic processor we can follow with the cubic real root (always exists). Using MATHEMATICA as the symbolic solver we submit

```
sols = Solve[m3 y''[t]^3 + m1 y''[t] + k1 y[t] + k3 y[t]^3 == f[t],y''[t]]
```

obtaining as real root

$$
y''(t) \to \frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(9 m_3^2 \left(f(t)-y(t) \left(k_3 y(t)^2+k_1\right)\right)+\sqrt{3} \sqrt{m_3^3 \left(27 m_3
   \left(-f(t)+k_3 y(t)^3+k_1 y(t)\right){}^2+4 m_1^3\right)}\right){}^{2/3}-2 \sqrt[3]{3} m_1 m_3}{6^{2/3} m_3 \sqrt[3]{9
   m_3^2 \left(f(t)-y(t) \left(k_3 y(t)^2+k_1\right)\right)+\sqrt{3} \sqrt{m_3^3 \left(27 m_3 \left(-f(t)+k_3 y(t)^3+k_1
   y(t)\right){}^2+4 m_1^3\right)}}}
$$

and after that we solve numerically the DE

```
m1 = 9.8845614144 10^-10;
m3 = 2.00030511601069 10^-12;
f1 = 1.66666666666667 10^-05;
k1 = 0.214188819381172;
k3 = 8.6610733212416;
omega = 2*Pi*(-82.454*t + 10030);
f[t_]:= f1*Sin[omega*t]
tmax = 1;
equ = y''[t] == (y''[t]/.sols[[1]]);
soly = NDSolve[{equ, y[0] == 0.1, y'[0] == 0.1},y,{t,0,tmax}][[1]];
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. soly], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]